# jQuery find by inline css attribute

Tags: jquery, css

I need to find an element based on a specific `css` attribute. The `css` is applied inline and I can not use a class.
Is there anyway to achieve this in `jQuery`?

Answer (score 28):

You could use an [attribute](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/attributeHas#attribute) selector

For example

```
$(":radio [style*='regular']")
```

would return a wrapped set of any input radios that contain `'regular'` in the style attribute

Comment: what if we have to make selection based on two values `left: 180px` and `top:360px`?

Comment: you just need to use multiple attribute selectors e.g. `$("[left='180px'][top='360px']")`

Comment: The link is broken.

Answer (score 18):

I think this is the cleanest solution. Say you want to find all elements where z-index has particular value:

```
$('*').filter(function () { return $(this).css('z-index') == 101 })
```

Answer (score 4):

I think you might be able to write a custom `jQuery` selector to do this.

For example, if you want to do select by certain style attribute, you can do:

```
 jQuery.extend(jQuery.expr[':'], {
    styleEquals: function(a, i, m){
        var styles = $(a).attr("style").split(" ")
        var found = false;
        for (var i = 0; i < styles.length; i++) {
            if (styles[i]===m[3]) {
                found = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        return found;
    }
});
```

Then it can be used in conjuction with any other selector you can select all input elements with certain style like this:

```
$('input:styleEquals('width=10px')')
```

Comment: this functionality is already included in the jQuery language.  all you need is $('selector[cssAttribute = value]')

Comment: jquery inbuilt selector works only if its an exact match , so it will only match if style = "absolute;" not if style = "absolute; left" . So the  solution I posted is for finding all elements with absolute value not only exact matches

Comment: @Surya: yep, I had a bad case of cerebro-rectal interitis.  Don't know what I was thinking.

Comment: I am getting (styles[i].equals(m[3])) is not a function
on this line if (styles[i].equals(m[3])) {

Comment: @Sammy I updated the code ..I didnt test it intially ..i just typed it in the browser.

Comment: @Surya, Thanks Surya I have already made that change using === instead
now if call it like   var ele = $("span:styleEquals('overflow=auto')");
alert(ele.Id);
the alert is always undefined.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, I think the fastest and easiest way to achieve the desired results would be to target styles with a property class selector.

Like stated before:

```
$('div.yourClass[style*="background-color:Blue"]).css('color', 'White');
```

That way we target all divs with same class that have blue background and tell them all to have white color text. Of course instead of `.css` we can use anything here, `.animate` and tell all blues to be animated etc. This helped me a lot with DB relations and people setting up strange things in DB.

I used to be less generic, and target strings with :contains... but then somebody goes to the base, and changes texts and labels, and bye bye code ;)

Hope it helps.

Comment: There is a typo in you code sir. `$('div.yourClass[style*="background-color:Blue"]').css('color', 'White');`

Answer (score 3):

Something like:

```
$('selector').each(function() {
    if($(this).attr('style').indexOf('font-weight') > -1) {
        alert('got my attribute');
    }
});
```

Comment: .indexOf can return 0, which will be evaluated to false

Answer (score 1):

```
var ccsStyle="font-weight:bold";
var els = [];
$("*").each(function(){
  var st = $(this).attr("style");
  if(st.indexOf(cssStyle) > -1) els.push(this);
});
//do stuff with els
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the attribute flag and use contains if you know the specific format that it's in.

```
$("[style*='position']")
```

This would find all the elements that define the position css attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You can search for any inline attribute with `.attr()` .. `.attr('attr_name')`

http://api.jquery.com/attr/

```
css_inline_value = $(element).attr('style');

if (css_inline_value = search_value) {
    // do stuff
}
```