# Select HTML element by CSS property value in style attribute

Tags: jquery

I have HTML like this:

```
…
<div style="top: 252px; left: 54px;"></div> 
<div style="top: 252px; left: 162px;"></div> 
<div style="top: 288px; left: 108px;"></div>
…
```

I have a JavaScript object literal like this:

```
var pos = { top: 252, left: 54 };
```

I want to select the element with the position that the object literal indicates. Positions are unique, so only one element will be selected.

Thank you for answers.

Comment: you can create a custom selector here is a SO link that will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1180067/jquery-find-by-inline-css-attribute/1180106#1180106

Comment: You can also use `.filter` to implement filtering yourself (use `.css` inside `.filter`).

Comment: I have posted the correct solution + jsfiddle sample in my post.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Credit goes to the original poster here;

[jQuery find by inline css attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1180067/jquery-find-by-inline-css-attribute)

The function is 'styleEquals' and can be implemented as;

```
jQuery.extend(jQuery.expr[':'], {
    styleEquals: function(a, i, m){
        var styles = $(a).attr("style").split(" ")
        var found = false;
        for (var i = 0; i < styles.length; i++) {
                if (styles[i]===m[3]) {
                        found = true;
                        break;
                }
        }
        return found;
    }
});
```

You can then search elements by their style attribute values using your new jquery extensions function such as;

```
$("div:styleEquals('top=252px'):styleEquals('left:54px')");
```

Comment: This solution works so I choose it as the accepted answer but in my problem I finally used id.

Answer (score 5):

All I can say is don't do this!

If you can add a unique position style to a div, you can equally easily add an identifier at the same time.

Use this identifier to select the element in javascript, not the css positioning.

Comment: Ok. Of course I can do it, I just wanted to ask if there is any possibility how to do this with css values.

Comment: but why would you want to? css is for styling elements, not identifying them! If you mix the two, you're creating a potential maintenance nightmare!

Comment: I could see why, what if this was some kind of game? And hundreds of elements were created dynamically. It would not make sense to create one separate CSS class for each and every position up front. Then you would have to select individual elements in some way. I have proposed a way to do this with jQuery out of the box.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it like this with [the jQuery JavaScript library](http://jquery.com/) out of the box:

```
var pos = { top: 252, left: 54 };
$('div[style*="top: ' + pos.top + 'px"][style*="left: ' + pos.left + 'px"]');
```

You need to make sure to use white space consistently. If you type:

```
<div style="top:252px; left:54px;"></div>
```

the proposed selector will not work.

You can also add other CSS properties to the `style` attribute by using my example code, and the order would not matter. Here is an example:

```
<div style="left: 54px; background: gray; top: 252px;"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
function findElement (top, left) {
    return target = $('div').filter(function() {
        var div = $(this);
        if (parseInt(div.css('top')) == top && parseInt(div.css('left')) == left )
            return true;
        return false;
    });
}
```

See the [jsfiddle sample](http://jsfiddle.net/Y8PmR/)

Answer (score 1):

When you generate these DIV, assign them with unique **id** attribute. Then you can retrieve the DIV object with the **id** attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Give them a class or id and select them using class/id, it will be much faster. Otherwise you'll need to find them all and filter by css values.

Answer (score 1):

you can select element by contents of style attribute (pay attention to spaces):

```
$('div[style*="top: 252px; left: 54px"]').css("color","red")
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/4zUeq/1/).

But like BonyT said - you should rather put the values into an id or class.