# Is it possible to set I-Frame source in a CSS style sheet?

Tags: css

I have a CSS style sheet utilising Media Queries. My homepage is just a background image 100% x 100% on to which I want to position a centered iframe, which will have a source based on the media query result.

EG:

**CSS**

```
@media all and (max-width: 500px) and (min-width: 400px), (min-width: 1151px)

.frame1{
 position:absolute;
 width:390px;  
 left:50%;
 margin-left:-195px;
 }
```

**HTML**

```
 <iframe class="frame1"></iframe>
```

So the width range is 400px to 500px and for any screen in this range the content will be in a centered iframe, with wider screen having a greater margin of background image visible. Now where my problem lays is I want the iframe source to change depending on screen size so I could have the source as mobile.htm (showing a very basic version of website) on small screens, standard.htm (a mid grade version) on average screens and large.htm (additional content included) on large screens.

However I can't get anything I have thought to do this. I assume to be determined by the media query it must be an attribute of the iframe listed in the CSS? I have tried every combination of:

frame src: **__**.htm;

iframe src: ***_***.htm;

frame src: url(***_*__**.htm);

iframe src: url(***_*__**.htm);

frame src: url ("***_*_**.htm");

etc.

*The underscores being the page name.

But so far nothing works.

Does anyone know if this is possible? If so how? And please be gentle with explanations I am very new to this, trying to self-teach as I go along and learning bits and pieces as I need them to achieve what I want... been going well so far, but has had me stumped for days now!

Comment: Did you try `<iframe class="frame1" src="frame.html"></iframe>`?

Comment: Thanks, but that was what first occurred to me, but that way the class renders the iframe size/shape/etc but the source is always the same I wanted the source linked to the class so that would also change.

Comment: CSS is about styling markup; Media Queries are about conditionnally styling this same markup, not the other way around. You should rely on other mechanisms to switch between different contents.

Answer (score 1):

You can [match based on attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#attrnmsp) but you can't set attributes using CSS only<sup>1</sup>

However, you could use a small snippet of JavaScript to detect the result of your media query (albeit indirectly):

- use the media query to apply a property value to the `IFRAME`
- select element(s) with that property value using JavaScript ([jQuery selectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1180067/jquery-find-by-inline-css-attribute) will work for this, although some iteration may be involved)
- update `src` accordingly

However, there really isn't a direct correlation between media queries and JavaScript. From an article on pairing media queries with JS:

> As far as I know there is no direct access to media queries from
>   JavaScript. You can’t read out whether the example media query above
>   has fired or not.

The [Full Article](http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2010/08/combining_media.html) suggests some script-based workarounds to return results from script which are consistent with the results of the media query.

<sup>1 - At least not in a standards-based fashion which is widely supported. There are hacks to execute code inside CSS using IE proprietary expressions (all of which are now deprecated).</sup>

Comment: Thanks, think I'm going to need to do a lot more reading to implement that... but nice to know what I want to achieve is possible and I'm not just banging my head against a brick wall!

Comment: It's a good question...I'm struggling to find a non-hack way to identify that a particular media query was actually applied. Your best bet might be to just test screen resolution manually with a little bit of script and update your `iframes` accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for that Tim, having been pointed in the right direction (combining CSS with script to test resolution) I think I have worked out a way to do it... Probably a very clumsy way by professional standards, but if it works it will do for me.

CSS media query to set iframe size, with all sizes calling same source - just a transparent page. With javascript to detect frame size and redirect accordingly in the hea of that page.