# Select LI children from a not none-displayed UL

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-selectors, css-selectors

The title sounds strange but what I want to achieve is simple.

In a tree of `ul`s I want to get all `li` children from any `ul` that have not the - inline - style `display: none`. So I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1180067/jquery-find-by-inline-css-attribute) and I mixed with the negation function [`:not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/). The result was:

```
'ul:not([style*="display: none"]) .k-item'
```

Where `.k-item` is a common class for all my `li` elements. That selector worked in [this simple fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h84qc/). The problem is that it doesn't works in my application. I have a screenshot of some console commands that will illustrate my scenario:

[image]

As you can see on second command, it returns some `li` elements that lies under an `ul` which haves `display: none` among other attributes in its inline style. Example of those unexpected `li` with attribute `data-uid` with values starting with `099d`, `bbca` and `14d2`.

I don't know what I'm doing wrong or if exists a better selector for that purpose.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest using jQuery's `:visible` rather than looking for something in the style string and string matching in the style string could be problematic.

```
$("ul:visible .k-item")
```

Comment: No changes, the same result.

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown - I fixed some missing quotes in my answer.  It works fine for me in this jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/Cxf74/.  Perhaps you could provide a demo where it doesn't work.

Comment: Yeah, strange. It worked on my fiddle test too. I'll try to reproduce a more accurate example on fiddle.

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown - is it possible that the `display: none` is being added to your your `<ul>` tags AFTER your javascript runs, thus they aren't there when the code runs?

Comment: The commands on the screenshot were run on a break-point just before the time its executed on the application. So it's on the right context and right time and there are the styles. It's so strange.

Comment: I have found someone else's fiddle with the widget from Kendo(Treeview) I'm using, right [here](http://jsfiddle.net/GHdwR/57/). I have added on the end two commands, one with the selector you provided and it worked. I don't know whats wrong with my code.

Answer (score 1):

First of all get all the li and check whether its parent (ul) is visible.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TQTLA/)

```
$('li', '#layers').each(function(){
    if($(this).parent().is(":visible")){
        alert($(this).text())
    }
});
```

OR

a neat version 
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GN4Dv/1/)

```
$(".k-item:visible").each(function(){
     alert($(this).text())
});
```

Comment: Nice, I'll try that later. But I prefer to be on the main loop selector because I need the `index` provided by the loop to be loyal to the match count. Its interesting because I can try `find('ul'):is(':visible').find('.k-item')`. Its ugly but ho cares.. haha thank you.

Comment: Thank you dude, but I have found the solution with `ul:visible > .k-item`. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
$('ul:not([style*="display: none"]) li.k-item').each(function() { alert($(this).html()) });
```

HTML

```
    <ul style="display: none">
       <li class="k-item">1</li>
       <li class="k-item">2</li>
       <li class="k-item">3</li>
    </ul>    
    <ul>
        <li class="k-item">4</li>
        <li class="k-item">5</li>
        <li class="k-item">6</li>
    </ul>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3M2ZM/

Comment: First off, `"k-item"` is not on the `<ul>` tags at all.  Please see the OP's actual document structure in the picture.

Comment: @jfriend00 class corrected using "k-item" instead of "kitem", same idea.

Comment: You're not solving the problem the OP is asking about.  They're trying to select `li` tags with the k-item class, not UL tags.

Comment: @jfriend00, change my answer to "Select LI children from a not none-displayed UL"

Comment: Looks like just what the OP had originally so I'm not sure what you've changed.