# How to change style element in an existing code using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, wordpress, element

I need to change style="z-index: 999999;" to style="z-index: 999;".
I tried the following jQuery but it doesn't change the number.
Would you please let me know how to change it?

I tried jQuery and I also tried in footer.php:

```
 jQuery('.pp-advanced-menu--dropdown [style="z-index: 999999;"]').each(function() 
 { this.setAttribute('style', 'z-index: 999;'); });

?>
<script>
$('.pp-advanced-menu--dropdown[style="z-index: 999999;"]').each(function() {this.setAttribute('style', 'z-index: 999;'); });
</script>
<?php
```

Existing code:

```
<body class="page-template">
<nav class="pp-advanced-menu--dropdown" style="z-index: 999999;"> 
<div class="pp-menu-close-wrap">Close</div>
</nav>
</body>
```

Thank you.

Comment: Remove the space: `'.pp-advanced-menu--dropdown[style="z-index: 999999;"]'`

Comment: Hi Alon: Thank you for your help. I tried it but it still doesn’t change the number. I also tried it in function.php (I updated the code)  but still no change...

Comment: How did you add this code from `functions.php`? (Note the **s** - The filename is NOT `function.php`). Make you you follow the instructions of adding the script as described [here](https://qodeinteractive.com/magazine/how-to-enque-scripts-wordpress/)

Comment: Hi Alon: oh, thank you for correcting me. I'm a nuewbie, very clumsy, sorry... I added like this, but it doesn't change the number => ?>
<script>
$('.pp-advanced-menu--dropdown[style="z-index: 999999;"]').each(function() {this.setAttribute('style', 'z-index: 999;'); });
</script>
<?php

Comment: Why is this in your `functions.php` file? You might consider adding this to your `footer.php` instead.

Comment: @disinfor: Hi, thank you for your comment. Oh, I din't know that. I put it to footer.php (https://i.imgur.com/2mN0tRU.jpg), but it still doesn't change the number...

Answer (score 3):

`.each()` is not necessary, as described in the [jQuery docs](https://api.jquery.com/each/).

Try:

```
jQuery('.pp-advanced-menu--dropdown[style="z-index: 999999;"]').css({'z-index' : 999});
```

(I also removed the space, as @AlonEitan suggested.)

Also see [jQuery find by inline css attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1180067/jquery-find-by-inline-css-attribute)

Comment: Hi kmoser: Thank you for your help. I tried your code but there is no change. I also tried your code in function.php but no change either...

Comment: @Fioi That's probably because you have a typo in your HTML: `<body class="page-template>` should be `<body class="page-template">` (missing close quote after `page-template`).

Comment: Hi kmoser: oh, thank you for the correction. I corrected the HTML, but the number still doesn't change. I added your code in functions.php but no change either. I added it like this => ?>
<script>
$('.pp-advanced-menu--dropdown[style="z-index: 999999;"]').css({'z-index' : 999});
</script>
<?php

Comment: @Fioi Did you put your script before or after the `.pp-advanced-menu--dropdown` element?

Comment: I put $('.pp-advanced-menu--dropdown between <script> and </script> . I'm a nuewbie, very clumsy, sorry...

Comment: Again, is that before or after the `.pp-advanced-menu--dropdown` element? For the JS to work, it must be *after* the element is defined.

Comment: ummm... sorry, I'm a newbie, very clumsy.. HTML code is created using Elementor. I put jQuery here -> https://i.imgur.com/ibHPglU.jpg, and I also tried to put it in footer.php -> https://i.imgur.com/M0gQh7f.jpg

Comment: Putting it in the footer, just before `</body>`, should work. But it's hard to say because we can't see the rest of the code on your page. StackOverflow works best when you reduce your question to a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Given the code you've provided in your original question, my solution works.

Comment: Hi kmoser: thank you for your comment, I put it before </body> (i.imgur.com/M0gQh7f.jpg), but still no change...

Comment: @Fioi Did you include the jQuery .js file itself? What messages or errors do you see in the console?

Comment: Hi kmoser: thank you for your supportive help. Console shows no error (Screenshot: https://i.imgur.com/cDuMVT3.jpg). I put jQuery in widget (Screenshot: https://i.imgur.com/ibHPglU.jpg), and this widget works well with other jQueries.

Comment: @Fioi I would add a simple test like `$('body').css('background-color', 'red')` to see if jQuery is working at all.

Comment: Hi kmoser: it works, I added  jQuery(".p-custom").attr("id","mylogin"); , and it changes the id. Both classes are in the same page (Screenshot=> https://i.imgur.com/d8W1HVW.jpg) As you can see, the numeber doesn't change but the id wordks.